# Required Pull Down To Refresh and Pull Up to Load More ListView in Android

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

My Application requires to fetch Data from Server in bulk. So I cannot get them all together and using paging concept. As data on my server changes frequently, I want to update it as soon as data changed. So I implemented Pull To Refresh Listview in my app but how to load more and more items in the listview. I don't find any listviews with Pull to refresh and pull up to load more functionality in Android as Iphone has. As of now i am using Endless Scroll listener concept but it won't work fine for my requirement. Putting button at the footer is not possible as I already put buttons over there as I have other requirement.